# Display HTML from Static Resource in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I have a HTML file in Static Resource, which I need to display in one of the sections as an overlay in Visualforce page.

How can this be achieved? I tried including directly, did not seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the fix, using jQuery.

```
//Get the URL of the HTML Page
var pageURL = "{!$Resource.ResourceName}/html/PageName.html";

//Load the HTML Content to the element(based on ID or Class)
$('.target-element').load(pageURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you copy the content of your HTML file into a new Visualforce page. After that, insert that Visualforce page in your Page Layout section, or if you use Visualforce, use apex:include to insert the new Visualforce page into the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is best practice, but I sometime use `<apex:include>` tag for same purpose.

First Create a VF page(say vftest) having HTML which you want to reference in other page.

> You can do standardstylesheet = false and showheader = false as
>   attributes of `<apex:page>`

then you can use this vf page(i.e.vftest) in any other VF page

```
 <apex:page >

 <apex:include pageName="vftest"/>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: Good idea and this will work. Perhaps using an apex:component would be more aligned with the requirement of inserting the html into a page.